refunding a settlement
Suppose a party sued or accused avoids trial by making a financial settlement that includes an agreement to keep the matter secret.
If the other party blabs, can they be forced to repay the settlement?  An answer elsewhere seems to say yes, but it's tagged 'canada' and we often hear in USA of such disclosures without anyone mentioning a demand for refund.
So, if that other question, referring to another country, is truly a duplicate, then why does it never happen in USA?
I'm not aware of it ever happening in USA, but it sort of seems like breach of contract.

One is Canada, and one is USA.  The former says yes, yet it seemingly never happens =in USA.  So, clearly not  duplicate.

Open or closed, it's still not a duplicate.
